# I've commited some project files using the git commit and git add . command but my files are not showing in the git repository

Tags: git

I have made an android studio project and i tried to add the project files to the git repository using the git commands,but as of now my repository was created but no files were added to the repository and the git bash status shows nothing to commit, working tree clean....Please suggest a solution

Comment: Take a look at the documentation. https://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial or https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials

Comment: Hi Harshdeep, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please go through the StackOverflow how to ask over here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . My suggestion is to go through the docs and try the Git Hub commands.

Comment: Do you mean your local or your remote repository? You need to `push` first if you want to see your changes on the remote repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/project-xxx.git

git push
```